# How can I use Xpath to find an element in node JS?

Tags: node.js, xpath, gauge, getgauge

I'm using gauge and taiko for automation, The problem is I'm unable to use xpath for click command on taiko.

await click($("//button[@class='btn-primary'][contains(.,'+ Add New')]"));

await click($("//html/body/form/div[3]/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button"));

await click($("//button[contains(@onclick,'Client360.prototype.OpenNewClientModal();')]"));

I have tried all of the above but getting the same error. "Custom selector not found.

Comment: Add the details about your question about what is the hierarchy of the page and what Xpath are you using. Is your XPath incorrect or you are getting non-desired element from the Xpath?

Comment: Don't tell us that you're unable to do something. Tell us what you tried and how it failed. Even if your approach was completely wrong, telling us what you attempted enables us to put you back on the right track.

Comment: @NikhilSahu I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: @MichaelKay I have updated the code in the question

Comment: The XPath expressions are syntactically valid, so I guess for some reason they're not matching anything in the target document.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with [taiko](https://github.com/getgauge/taiko). Could you please raise an issue? XPath selectors are supposed to work, and these seem like valid XPath expressions as mentioned by @MichaelKay

Comment: @ShahidMehmoodAwan
Please add html snippet for which you are trying to use xpath and also provide complete js file code along with imports

Answer (score 0):

`$()` uses backticks(```` ) not double-inverted comma("). try changing 
```await click($("//button[@class='btn-primary'][contains(.,'+ Add New')]"))``` to 
```await click($( ````//button[@class='btn-primary'][contains(.,'+ Add New')]`))```.

Hope this helps!